# JDBC Driver Not in CLASSPATH eroor

Tags: command-line

I have try to running apirior alogorithm in IdeaJ IDE. Where the following error occur

```
Trying to add database driver (JDBC): Driver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?
```

How do I overcome this error. I have to issues.

1. How Do I install JDBC Driver in Ubuntu
2. How Am I get the path and add in CLASSPATH

Answer (score 2):

1. Install the connector driver.

   `sudo apt-get install libmysql-java`
2. The next step is to make sure that the classpath is set. You can have this set automatically by adding this a command to you bashrc file.

   `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set this for all users or permanently, you should modify the 
sudo /etc/profile.
just enter this command on terminal
2.sudo gedit /etc/profile
and set CLASSPATH following as
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar 
it work perfectly please try

Comment: Please avoid posting two separate answers. You can edit your first answer any number times and change/modify/append the contents at any time. No restrictions. So please shift (copy & paste) the contents of your 2nd answer to 1rst and then remove (delete) your 2nd answer. Just below your first answer, you will find three fields viz. `share`, `edit`, `flag`. You just use `edit`. Hope you get my point.